# wildcarded httphandler with mvc no longer working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this

```
      <add name="xxx" verb="GET,POST,PUT" path="xxx/*" type="...." />
```

Ie any url that looks like xxx/anything should go to that handler. Now that this is cohosted in an MVC app it no longer works. It seems that I need some derivative of

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

but I cannot work out the correct incantation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has to be

```
public class XXXRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new XxxHandler(); // the original http handler
    }
}
```

and

```
     var xxxroute = new Route("xxx/{*pathinfo}", new XXXRouteHAndler());
     routes.Add(xxxroute);
```

in RegisterRoutes

Correction: better is

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("xxx/{*ignore}");
```